# link_to method and click event in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I create a link of this type:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('search').value=this.value">
```

using method `link_to` in Rails?

I couldn't figure it out from [Rails docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html).

Comment: Unless you've just left the '#' for brevity, there doesn't seem to be much point in using link_to.  Why not just use an a tag with the onclick set as you've done above.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

You can use [`link_to_function`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#M001756) (removed in Rails 4.1):

```rb
link_to_function 'My link with obtrusive JavaScript', 'alert("Oh no!")'
```

Or, if you absolutely need to use [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M001597):

```rb
link_to 'Another link with obtrusive JavaScript', '#',
        :onclick => 'alert("Please no!")'
```

However, putting JavaScript right into your generated HTML is **obtrusive**, and is **bad practice**.

Instead, your Rails code should simply be something like this:

```rb
link_to 'Link with unobtrusive JavaScript',
        '/actual/url/in/case/javascript/is/broken',
        :id => 'my-link'
```

And assuming you're using the [Prototype JS framework](http://prototypejs.org/), JS like this in your `application.js`:

```js
$('my-link').observe('click', function (event) {
  alert('Hooray!');
  event.stop(); // Prevent link from following through to its given href
});
```

Or if you're using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```js
$('#my-link').click(function (event) {
  alert('Hooray!');
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent link from following its href
});
```

By using this third technique, you guarantee that the link will follow through to some other page—not just fail silently—if JavaScript is unavailable for the user. Remember, JS could be unavailable because the user has a poor internet connection (e.g., mobile device, public wifi), the user or user's sysadmin disabled it, or an unexpected JS error occurred (i.e., developer error).

Comment: link_to_function wasn't removed but introduced in Rails 3. I guess you meant link_to_remote.

Comment: `link_to_function` has been around since Rails 1.0, but you're right that it wasn't removed; it was deprecated (and then un-deprecated, and then it flipped a few more times). I'll update my answer. Thanks!

Comment: If I has a list of stocks, and wanted to do something similar. How will I get the stock symbol into the click function?

Comment: How would you pass a parameter to your javascript function when using the `$('#my-link').click()` solution? Like the current id of a record. Is there a rails way to do this? Or only solution would be to add `"record-id" => "<%= @record.id %>"` to the `link_to`?

Answer (score 25):

To follow up on Ron's answer if using JQuery and putting it in application.js or the head section you need to wrap it in a ready() section...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#my-link').click(function(event){
    alert('Hooray!');
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent link from following its href
  });
});
```

Comment: Note that this can be shortened to `$(function() { ... });`, which is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: By the way [jquery 3.0](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) recommends to use `$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});` instead of **$(document).ready()**

Comment: for rails 5 with turbolinks use: $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {

Answer (score 10):

just use

```
=link_to "link", "javascript:function()"
```

Answer (score 1):

another solution is catching onClick event and for aggregate data to js function you can

.hmtl.erb

```
<%= link_to "Action", 'javascript:;', class: 'my-class', data: { 'array' => %w(foo bar) } %>
```

.js

```
// handle my-class click
$('a.my-class').on('click', function () {
  var link = $(this);
  var array = link.data('array');
});
```