# Rails: write onclick code in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

You may find this very basic question but I am not getting how to write this code in rails:

```
  <input type='image' src='http://images.aviary.com/images/edit-photo.png' value='Edit photo' onclick="return launchEditor('image1', 'http://images.aviary.com/imagesv5/feather_default.jpg');" />
```

I am uploading photos and need to use above code for edit photos.

Here i want to use this code:

```
<%= image_tag photo.object.avatar.url(:thumb), :class => "foodio_photo" unless f.object.new_record? or photo.object.new_record? %>
```

Please help! I am newbie.

Comment: I believe your problem can be solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698858/link-to-method-and-onclick-event-in-rails

Comment: Please provide the erb code where you want to do this in case you haven't solved it yet.

Comment: hey @wintermeyer, added the code where i want to write html-js code

Answer (score 0):

First off, the place to put the onclick is in the javascript file. That said, this should work:

"foodio_photo", :onclick => "doSomethingWith(this)") unless f.object.new_record? or photo.object.new_record? %>