# How to generate a button tag with nested elements

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, onclick

I want to be able to generate a button tag with a nested icon element.

Particularly, I want to be able to use this:

```
<%= tag "input", { "class" => "btn btn-info", "type" => "button", "onclick"=> "codeAddress()" }%>
```

but with nested icon.

I tried putting in class `icon-search`, it worked but it didn't looked good.

I stumbled upon so many questions, they pointed at solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9401942/using-link-to-with-embedded-html).

And I altered the code of line to this :

```
<%= tag "input", { "class" => "btn btn-info", "type" => "button", "onclick"=> "codeAddress()" } do %>
       <i class="icon-search"></i>
<% end %>
```

But none of them worked.

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698858/link-to-method-and-onclick-event-in-rails) does not seem to do it neither.

I am using `Rails 4` and `Twitter-bootstrap-rails 2.x`

Comment: What part of it doesn't work? Can you give the error you're seeing or the rendered HTML that is incorrect?

Comment: try using a `button` tag. I don't think `input` accepts children as it's a self closing tag

Comment: @busches, There's no erro whatsoever, the only 'not working' part is that the icon does not show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= button_tag "name", type: 'button', class: "btn btn-info", onclick: "codeAddress()" do %>
   <i class="icon-search"></i>
<% end %>
```